# Laravel, Eloquent upsert method Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do a bulk update using the upsert method. But I get a duplication error. Is there anyway I can make this method accept a composite unique key? I'm using mariadb as a database.

bd structure

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
CONSTRAINT UC_Person UNIQUE (ID,LastName)
);
```

php

```
        return $this->persons->upsert($personsData, ['ID', 'LastName'], $fieldsToUpdate);
```

Comment: `$personData` contains multiple entries that would create a duplicate on the unique columns or there's already a record in the database that clashes with one of your

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm i understant, but upsert must update the record in this case or not?

Comment: If `$persondData` contains duplicates, I think no.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm no, there is a duplicate in the table, there are no duplicates in the array, I checked

Comment: `upsert` is very simple; `updateOrCreate` provides more flexibility to define when you want an update or a create to happen.

Comment: @miken32 yes, but updateOrCreate only works with one record

Comment: Ah, you will probably be stuck with a manual query using `DB` facade then. Or a loop with `updateOrCreate`, but I wouldn't suggest that unless you have a small number of records  like < 1000.

Comment: @miken32 I have more than 10k entries. Is it normal practice to do something like `DB::query("UPDATE SET ..... WHERE ....; UPDATE SET ..... WHERE ....;UPDATE SET ..... WHERE .. ..;......")`, that is, create a string of this format and send it to DB::query()? I just don't like it very much =)

Comment: Personally I would do this outside Laravel if there are that many. That way you can prepare a statement and execute inside a loop. Laravel isn't great for providing low-level access to things, which can be an issue with larger datasets. Since the dupe target I used is for a single entry, I'll reopen and see if anyone else has better suggestions.